# Will this VBA code execute Asynchronously

Tags: c#, ms-access

Ok so I am trying to automate Microsoft Access from C#. Obviously you can't execute VBA code Asynchronously in VBA itself, but my idea was to brute force this from C# using delegates.

We have a legacy reporting system which runs hundreds of badly designed queries to get information, and these queries run synchronously inside Macros. Each query was designed using the MS Access query designer, and queries a MySql database over ODBC. They take 2-3 minutes to run and a Macro may contain <=20 queries, meaning the Macro will take the best part of an hour to run. If I ran these async, I could run the entire Macro in a couple of minutes.

My full C# code is below:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

namespace AsyncVBA
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Application ap;
        private delegate void ExportThread(string queryName, string exportLocation);

        private static int count;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbName = @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\MyDatabase.accdb";
            count = 0;

            ExportThread queryThread = new ExportThread(ExportQuery);

            ap = new Application();
            ap.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbName);

            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryOne", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\one.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryTwo", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\two.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryThree", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\three.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryFour", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\four.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryFive", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\five.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qrySix", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\six.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qrySeven", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\seven.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryEight", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\eight.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryNine", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\nine.xlsx", null, null);
            queryThread.BeginInvoke("qryTen", @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x\ten.xlsx", null, null);

            while (count < 10)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            ap.CloseCurrentDatabase();
        }

        private static void ExportQuery(string queryName, string exportLocation)
        {
            ap.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(AcDataTransferType.acExport, AcSpreadSheetType.acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, queryName, exportLocation);
            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

I am having two issues currently, the first is that my code still seems to be executing synchronously, could this be to do with a limitation in MS Access. I'm guessing MS Access is queuing the requests as it receives them or something. The second, less important problem, is that my count doesn't seem to be incrementing.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's to run VBA code Asynchronously using C#, the exports are just an example of the type of VBA code I want to run.

Comment: In that case what evidence supports "my code still seems to be executing synchronously"?  Is it simply that you don't get a hoped-for speed increase, so you assume those operations are not executing asynchronously?

Comment: Verify your assumption then.  If those "hundreds of badly designed queries" require massive amounts of data transfer across the network, that may well be the bottleneck.  And, if that is so, executing the queries asynchronously will not help (either very little or not at all) ... because they will still need to wait on the data they need.

Comment: I think count should be static.  I was hoping not static would be why count was incrementing.   Agree with all that has been said about Access possibly being the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, launching word, Excel, power point or any of the office suites will not run anything asynchronously.  In fact, if you created an instance of SQL server, you would find the same thing. (big difference between sending a SQL command to SQL SEPARATE process as opposed to creating an in-process instance.

I would consider writing out this data to a text file, or even a temp table, and then shell() out an instance of the application that are on startup runs the series of quires. You could even create a windows script here that executes these commands. That way you get a separate instance and thread and your application will thus not have to wait.

Answer (score 7):

Just speaking from a lot of experience with Access as a front end, the best is to change all the queries to Pass-through queries and rewrite them in the mySQL syntax.

The reason the current method takes so long is probably that the data set passed over the network is far larger than it needs to be. Access passes over what the mySQL DB can interpret and then applies the rest of the sql syntax upon arrival. It's very inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: I asked this quite a while ago but thanks for taking the time to answer, I have learned this the hard way since asking and have indeed rewrote a good many queries in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in Microsoft Access was designed to run at the same time as anything else. I am pretty sure that when you successfully open an Access database, you gain an exclusive lock on all the system tables. I cannot see how it can work any other way.

A much better approach would be to extract the SQL from the Access database. You say that each query was designed using the query designer (I think you mean the design view), but it still has SQL that you can get at. Just switch from design view to SQL view, and there you have it

Comment: Hmm I was trying to avoid this. The issue here is that the SQL isn't MySQL so every query has to be converted, then the names of the linked tables have all been changes in Access so for example, tblOne in MySql could have been changed to tblAccessOne inside Access, which means that every instance of tblAccessOne inside every query needs to be changed to tblOne to run the MySql query directly. This is what I was doing originally and it got very messy very quickly!

Comment: You could create MySQL views to mimic the MS Access select queries. The SQL is not going to be that different.